# copy cell to selected date range

Tags: excel, date, copy, range

I have a list of dates in B2:GF2. I enter 2 dates - "A1 start date and B1 End date". I also enter a value (number) in cell C1. The value in C1 should be copied to all the cells under the list of dates from A2:GF2 between the dates choosed in A1 and B1. Let the copied value between the row A3:GF3.

E.g.:

```
          A   |   B      |  C 
 Row1 3/3/2015| 5/5/2015 | ABC
 Row2           2/2/2015 | 3/3/2015 | 4/4/2015 | 4/23/2015 | 5/5/2015....
                            ABC          ABC        ABC        ABC
```

Comment: What have you tried? Without that we cannot tell if you're more into Excel worksheet functions or VBA code? Can you share the options that you thought would have worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

In cell C4, type `=IF(AND(C3>=$A$2,C3<$B$2),$C$2,"")`, then just copy cell C4 across.